# can't order results by distance using Google Api

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api

I am making a call into this URL: `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=60.16915,24.9293937&radius=20000&keyword=k+rauta&rankBy=distance&key=KEY`

For some reason I am unable to order result by closest shop the first.
Like in documentation from https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_search_requests I added **rankBy=distance** but still it does not seem the result is ordered correctly!

I removed radius parameter as well but then I get no result found at all!

Any idea what I am missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I read the documentation you mentioned:

> `google.maps.places.RankBy.DISTANCE`. This option sorts results in ascending order by their distance from the specified `location` (required). **Note that you cannot specify a custom `bounds` and/or `radius`** if you specify `RankBy.DISTANCE`. When you specify `RankBy.DISTANCE`, one or more of `keyword`, `name`, or `type` is required.

Adapt your request with the above and it will work.

**Edit:**

You are obviously mixing 2 different things (sorry I didn't see that at first). The Places **Library** to which you pointed your documentation link, and the [Places API Web Service](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search) which is a different thing.

They both are very similar but there is at least one difference: the `rankBy` parameter is `rankby` in the web service. Note the uppercase/lowercase `B`.

So this will work: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=60.16915,24.9293937&keyword=k+rauta&name=k+rauta&type=hardware_store&rankby=distance&key=your_api_key

Also note that your last attempt (link in your comment) returns `INVALID_REQUEST` and not `ZERO_RESULTS` or anything else which should help you understand there is problem with your request, and not with the fact that there is no data to return...

Comment: I removed radius and I get no result at all (INVALID_REQUEST). could you provide the url wich will get the result by closest first?

Comment: i see i have to have keyword, name and type as required field in this case

Comment: tried smth like this: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=60.16915,24.9293937&keyword=k+rauta&name=k+rauta&type=hardware_store&rankBy=distance&key=key still not working!